# Recommended structure for testing Javascript with QUnit in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, qunit

I have a standard ASP.NET MVC (version 2 preview 2) solution with the actual project and server-side unit tests in separate projects.

Because this project is very client-side heavy, I want to make a ClientTest project as well that uses QUnit to test the main project.

I've thought of creating a regular ASP.NET webforms project with a single HTML file that would load the various scripts in my Scripts/ directory and test them with QUnit.  Unfortunately this will spawn another ASP.NET Development Server.  I could configure the port of the running MVC project server before running the tests, but there's got to be a better way that isn't just throwing the test html file into the main MVC project.

Does anyone know of a better way of going about this?

Comment: How did it all ended up. Could you share a sample?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I like your idea of placing the QUnit tests in a separate project. What about using `XCOPY` to copy the scripts in the pre-build event?

Say your MVC project is **MyProj.Web** and your QUnit test project is **MyProj.ClientTest** (replace with your project names).

- Create a Scripts folder in your ClientTest project.
- From *Project > **MyProj.ClientTest** Properties > Build Events*, add the following to *Pre-build event command line*:

  XCOPY "$(SolutionDir)MyProj.Web\Scripts" "$(ProjectDir)Scripts" /S /Y
- Then in your HTML just include the appropriate JavaScript files from the Scripts folder.

Note: You will have to rebuild your ClientTest project to refresh JavaScript files when you want to rerun tests. Adjust folder names, paths and `XCOPY` options as needed.

Comment: Consider including the following instruction first. Otherwise there's a risk of having orphaned files accumulating in the target directory.

`DEL "$(ProjectDir)Scripts\Web\*.js"`

"web" is the sub directory into which I copy the .js files to be tested.

Comment: Could you share a sample?

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you could pick and choose techniques from [this article](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/joshuaflanagan/archive/2008/09/18/running-jquery-qunit-tests-under-continuous-integration.aspx), including using the command-line, harnessing NUnit with WatiN, and scraping test results for reporting. This solution wouldn't require a separate WebForms project to harness the tests in, since it's all handled by WatiN.

Comment: Using WaitiN is an interesting idea, but not exactly what I want. Since on the client side I have a whole MVC framework running I want to have tests that aren't visual at all, and I also don't want to have test pages in the main project.

Answer (score 2):

It's not too clear to me why using MVC makes a difference - if you want to integrate your tests into a CI build then gWiz's suggestion is the route to go.

If your requirement is that you want to run your tests interactively directly on the real page without affecting the look of that page then you could check out the [FireUnit](http://fireunit.org/) plugin for Firebug. You can also wrap FireUnit around QUnit as described on [John Resig's blog](http://ejohn.org/blog/fireunit/).

If you're concerned about including test stuff then include the relevant scripts in your test/debug builds and disable/remove them in your production builds.